# while with raw_input creating an infinite loop

Tags: python

In these lines:

```
foo = []

a = foo.append(raw_input('Type anything.\n'))
b = raw_input('Another questions? Y/N\n')

while b != 'N':
    b = foo.append(raw_input('Type and to continue, N for stop\n'))
    if b == 'N': break

print foo
```

How to do the loop break?
 Thanks!

Comment: You're assuming the wrong problem. To debug this it would be a good idea to print `foo` inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list.append returns None.

```
a = raw_input('Type anything.\n')
foo = [a]
b = raw_input('Another questions? Y/N\n')

while b != 'N':
    b = raw_input('Type and to continue, N for stop\n')
    if b == 'N': break
    foo.append(b)
```

Comment: note that if he wants to use `a` it won't be the `raw_input` return but whatever `foo.append` returns

Comment: @Blam People all over this question seem to forget that `list.append()` does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it

```
foo = []

a = raw_input('Type anything.\n')
foo.append(a)
b = raw_input('Another questions? Y/N\n')

while b != 'N':
    b = raw_input('Type and to continue, N for stop\n')
    if b == 'N': break
    foo.append(raw_input)

print foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the last element added to `foo`:

```
while b != 'N':
    foo.append(raw_input('Type and to continue, N for stop\n'))
    if foo[-1] == 'N': break   # <---- Note foo[-1] here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning b to the result of a list append which is None. Even if you were lookking at foo, you would be looking at the list created by the foo.append and then comparing it to the charcter 'N'. Even if you only type N at the input, the value of foo would at least look like ['N']. You could eliminate b altogether with:

```
while True:
    foo.append(raw_input('Type and to continue, N for stop\n'))
    if 'N' in foo: break
```

Though this would leave the 'N' character in your list. Not sure if that is intended or not.